# Rails weird capture block error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capture, block

I have a helper method 'default_content_for' which can be used to provide default content for yield sections. However when I'm using it, I get weird output from the helper.

I'm pretty sure I'm probably missing something simple, but still not sure what is wrong.

The title ends up full of stuff above the beginning of the block. Like so:

```
<title>   Default Title&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt; &lt;html&gt; &lt;head&gt;      &lt;title&gt;   Default Title   </title>
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>
  <% default_content_for :title do %>
    Default Title
  <% end %>
  </title>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>


<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>
  <% default_content_for :title do %>
    Default Title
  <% end %>
  </title>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>


<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

helper method

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def default_content_for(name, &block)
      name = name.kind_of?(Symbol) ? ":#{name}" : name
      out = eval("yield #{name}", block.binding)
      out = (out ? (out.empty? ? false : out): false) || capture(&block)
      concat(out)
    end
end
```

output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>

  <title>   Default Title&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt; &lt;html&gt; &lt;head&gt;      &lt;title&gt;   Survey Builder   </title>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1314309079"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/effects.js?1314309079"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1314309078"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/controls.js?1314309078"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/rails.js?1314309079"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/application.js?1314309078"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param">
<meta content="oG4mVUt5wy6aWdhbxmXa3tYh3DUgXVUQy9d6uxng6a0=" name="csrf-token">
</head>
<body>

<div id="user_nav">
        Logged in as KARL KIRCH
        <a href="/log_out">Log out</a>
</div>


<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>




</body></html>
```

Comment: Where is the content_for(:title) you are calling, as your method refers to it by evaling the name symbol. Also, i find the nested terinary to be very tricky to read, especially over time. I recommend changing it to proper if statements for better long term use. Or if you dont need out = false, then just do: `out ||= capture(&block)`

Comment: Fixed my helper method, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I should read things. 
In rails 3 blocks are supposed to use the following form:

```
<%= default_content_for :title do %>
<% end %>
```

Also helper methods are supposed to only return a string not a concat, so I changed my helper method like so (with suggestion from agmcleod

```
  module ApplicationHelper
    def default_content_for(name, &block)
      name = name.kind_of?(Symbol) ? ":#{name}" : name
      out = eval("yield #{name}", block.binding)
      if out && !out.empty?
        out
      else
        capture(&block)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I was actually thinking that might be the case, but I wasn't certain as I've never really used/seen Concat before. The fact it was outputting something gave me doubt there.